# Error - The type 'TEntity' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, repository-pattern

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : Entity
{
    private IDbSet<TEntity> GetSet()
    {
       return _unitOfWork.CreateSet<TEntity>();
    }
}
```

In the above code am getting following error on **GetSet()**

> Error 1   The type 'TEntity' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'TEntity' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.Entity.IDbSet'    E:\Pradeep\Workshop\WebAPI\Extras\DDD\DDD.WebAPI\4.DDD.Infrastructure\Repository\Repository.cs  44  33  4.DDD.Infrastructure

Comment: What is `Entity`? Is it a `struct ` or an interface?

Answer (score 4):

On your `Repository` class you have a generic constraint on the type parameter `TEntity`:

```
where TEntity : Entity
```

In entity framework, entities must be classes (enforced by a `where T : class` constraint). Since you get the error, `Entity` is not a class. The only possibilities are that it is a `struct` or an interface. Depending on that, the solutions to your problem are entirely different:

1. If `Entity` is a `struct`, you need to change it to a `class`. EF will not allow you to create an entity set with value types.
2. If `Entity` is an interface, you need to forward the reference type constraint to your repository class (and maybe while you're at it rename your interface to `IEntity` to comply with .NET coding guidelines).

Here's the code if `Entity` is an interface:

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, Entity
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! Thank you!! 
After spending 2h wondering what was going wrong and almost going mad, you hit the nail in the head, my model class was a struct. Changing it to a class fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

If you add `class` to the `where` statement then the compiler will know that it can only be a reference type. Like this:

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : Entity, class
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: If `Entity` is a `struct` this will cause a compiler error.

Comment: @Sefe then the OP will 10 steps closer to figuring out the problem :)

Comment: @CallumLinington: Yeah, but probably not to enlightmenment. If `Entity` is a struct, making the class generic makes zero sense, because the only valid type parameter would be `Entity` (there's not inheritance for `structs`).

Comment: @Sefe I prefer this as part of the solution, because it utilising the compiler properly to catch errors early

Comment: BTW, even with `Entity` being an interface, the compiler will reject the solution. The `class` constraint has to come before any interface constraint.